# Menu input: Once invalid input is detected, all inputs are deemed invalid

Tags: c++, while-loop, getline

I have a menu creation system with a vector of strings the user can select from, and as such only integers that are within the menu options are allowed as valid input.

If a number is properly entered, everything works fine. If there is an incorrect input (a string, float, negative number, etc.) nothing will happen, when it is supposed to display an error message.

If an attempt is made to enter anything else (valid or not), the error message will then appear for every subsequent entry and the user is stuck.

This is the loop I'm using to validate the code -

```
bool check = false;
string line;
std::stringstream temp;
int input;

while(!check)
{
    getline(cin, line);
    temp << line;
    temp >> std::noskipws >> input; //this is supposed to reject spaces and floats

    if(!temp.fail() && temp.eof() && input > 0 && input <= static_cast<int>(options.size()))
    {
        check = true; //returns valid value and stops loop
    }
    else //if all conditions aren't met
    {
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore();
        cout << wrongInput << endl; //prints error
    }
}
return input; //correctly returns when valid on first try
```

Before this, I simply used cin >> input and cin.fail() to check, but that allowed floats to pass and would display the error message multiple times for string entries.

If there's any missing info please let me know, but I think everything here is what's relevant.

---

EDIT: was just testing my program with only-correct inputs and it began to seemingly arbitrarily fail.

Example of incorrect input:

```
(menu with numbered options)
intput: "abba" || "3.2" || "4 3" || "-4" || etc.
(no response)
input: "valid number"
(please enter a number from above) - repeats indefinitely
```

Example of correct input:

```
(menu with numbered options)
input: "1"
(correctly executes "1" selection, shows menu again)
input: "1"
(again correctly executes "1" selection, shows menu again)
input: "1"
(no response)
input: "1"
(please enter a number from above) - repeats indefinitely
```

Comment: Give us an example of the input.

Comment: The `eof` flag won't be set if the line contains a valid integer value. It's not set until you attempt to read from beyond the end of the "file".

Comment: I also recommend you think about what [the `>>` operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt2) *returns*, and how a stream can be used in a [boolean expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool).

Comment: Why are you checking `temp.eof()` ?

Comment: also you never reset the error conditions on `temp` at any point

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude if eof flag isn't set, wouldn't it not return correct values at all?

Comment: @M.M I check eof because I thought otherwise it passes multi-character entries into the next arguments. eg. "3.2" will first pass 3, then before the user can make another entry it will pass "2" as if it were the next input.

Comment: `eof` doesn't mean to check if there are any unread characters. Also there should not be a next prompt anyway, you should discard `temp`

Answer (score 0):

There's some problems with the code you show. Lets start with that you don't check the status of reading from `std::cin`. If there's a failure or the user pressed the end-of-file sequence you won't detect it.

Secondly, there's no need to reset the flags of `std::cin`, and there's definitely no need to `ignore` any input from `std::cin` either.

Thirdly, as I mentioned, the `eof` flag will *not* be set in the `temp` string stream. And there's better way to check for error flags or `eof` as well.

Fourthly, if you don't want negative numbers, use an *unsigned* integer type, and the stream extraction will fail if it's negative.

Lastly, and this is more of a personal opinion, why not allow leading space? There's really nothing wrong with it.

With all this said and done, I would do it something like this instead:

```
unsigned input;

std::string line;
while (std::getline(std::cin, line))
{
    // Define stream inside the loop, no need to reset it when the loop iterates
    std::istringstream istr(line);

    // Attempt to extract the value, checking range
    if (istr >> input && input > 0 && input <= options.size())
    {
        // All went okay, the input is valid
        break;
    }

    // If we reach here, there was an error parsing the input
    // Or the input was out of bounds
    std::cout << wrongInput << '\n';
}

if (!std::cin)
{
    // Could not even read from standard input, consider this a fatal error
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

// Here the variable input contains a value that is larger than zero and smaller or equal to options.size()
```

If you need to do this multiple times, then I of course recommend that you put the above code into its own function that you can call. Then if there's a failure you could return `0` instead of `EXIT_FAILURE`, to indicate an error of any kind.

Comment: (edit: this is a part of its own function) Thank you for explaining everything, but I am still getting odd failures.


https://i.imgur.com/KDvWPQF.png


Even after a correct entry, after displaying the menu it displays an error message (which it didn't do before). It will still accept floats and spaces, then seems to ignore  only part of subsequent input. At one point, it simply didn't respond until the same entry was made again. I didn't change what you posted at all except for using "endl" instead of '\n'

Comment: @ZJN [Works fine for me](https://ideone.com/OYdcpO). First call reads the invalid value `-1`, then loops and read the valid value `1` which it returns. The second call reads the invalid value `0`, loops and return the valid value `2`. The third call reads and return the valid value `3` (the `5` on the same input line is silently ignored). The fourth call reads the invalid value `4`, loops and reached EOF and returns with `0` indicating error. The fifth call also fails to read from `std::cin` and return with `0` indicating error.